# How to change detailTextLabel height programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, height

I programmed an array into a `tableView`. When the cell utilizes more than one line for the `detailTextLabel`, the space in between the lines is small. I would like to know if there is any way to increase this height programmatically? Here is sample code I am using for the array.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.filtered[indexPath.row].coptic
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filtered[indexPath.row].english
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"CS Avva Shenouda", size:30)
cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Constantia", size:25)
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

return cell
```

Comment: very nice suggestion, Use custom tableview cell and design it according to your requirement

Comment: Agreed, custom cells give you all the control you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just putting my logic, not whole code.
You can get height of string by below code

```
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
```

Change `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 
let height = height(withConstrainedWidth:200, font:YourFont) // change width and font as per your requirement 
cell.detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: cell.detailTextLabel?.frame.origin.x, y: cell.detailTextLabel?.frame.origin.y, width: cell.detailTextLabel?.frame.size.width, height: height)
```

You can manage cell height according to detailTextLabel height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
   return 50 // You should put your code or logic that dynamic height based on heigh of label.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The table view needs to have an estimatedRowHeight and the tableView height as UITableViewAutomaticDimension.